# Get all media files in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, media-player, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Media Player for Windows 8 and I need to read all the music in the Windows Media Player media library.

How I can do that in WinRT C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to select `Music Library` contract in `Appmanifest>Capabilities` which will allow you to get all music file's in the User's music library. But the user can always decline your app the permission to use the Music Library.

```
        var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

Comment: @GiulioZausa you shouldn't really be asking for the code, but what the heck, check updated answer.